# Enforce member alignment of a SIMD data type

Tags: c++, alignment, simd

I have a class with a NEON SIMD data type that looks like this:

```
class Change {
    void clear() {
        m_d = vdupq_n_s32(0);
    }
private:
    uint32x4 m_d;    
};
```

compiling using clang for ARM, when I run this on most Android devices, it just works fine.
On some devices however calling `clear()` causes SIG_BUS, Alignment fault and true enough, when I check the address of `m_d` it turns out not aligned to 16 bytes (the size of `uint32x4` as it should)
The solution was to add:

```
class Change {
    void clear() {
        m_d = vdupq_n_s32(0);
    }
private:
    uint32x4 m_d;    
} __attribute__((aligned(16)));
```

This indeed solved most of the cases where `Change` is instantiated on its own, but it did not solve cases like:

```
class Something {
    void* m_ptr;
    Change m_change;
};
```

When instantiating `Something` change would again get an address that is not aligned. In this case adding again `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` to `Something` solved it but it raises a troubling issue
- isn't the alignment declaration in `Change` transferred to `Something`?
- is there a better way to do this than to go looking for all of the places `Change` is instantiated and add `__attribute__((aligned(16)))`?

Comment: What happens if you use the standard `alignas` specifier rather than the non-standard `aligned` attribuite?

Comment: Does it help or have any effect to apply an `alignas`, or `__attribute__` to the `uint32x4` itself, rather than the class as a whole?  If it works, this might be better practice in general for C++.  I forget if virtual member function pointers go at the front or back of the layout of a class, but if they come first, they'll affect the alignment of other members for classes with virtual member functions.

Comment: `alignas` has the same effect as `__attribute__`. adding it on the `uint32x4` has no effect

Answer (score 0):

Please check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn736986.aspx
Visual Studio sometime causes misaligments in ARM processors.